# Jetplayer vs. soundPool?

Tags: android, performance, android-widget

This is my Main activity and i believe thats all you need to see if anyone can help me....

```
package com.art.drumdrum;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
SoundPool soundPool = null;
int kickId = 0;
int snareId = 0;
int crashhId = 0;
int crashlId = 0;
int muteId = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button kick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kick);
    Button snare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.snare);
    Button crashh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.crashh);
    Button crashl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.crashl);

    kick.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)
                soundPool.play(kickId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            return false;
        }
    });
    snare.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)
                soundPool.play(snareId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            return false;
        }
    });
    crashh.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)
                soundPool.play(crashhId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            return false;
        }
    });
    crashl.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)
                soundPool.play(crashlId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            return false;
        }
    });

}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (soundPool == null) {
        soundPool = new SoundPool(20, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        kickId = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.kick, 1);
        snareId = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.snare, 1);
        crashhId = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.crashh, 1);
        crashlId = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.crashl, 1);
    }
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (soundPool != null) {
        soundPool.release();
        soundPool = null;
    }
}

}
```

I was wondering if using a JetPlayer would work better then a soundPool in the case of what i am trying to do. I have it so i can hit multi- buttons and sound plays at same time and all seems well, but there is a small lag from when you hit the button till it plays the sound, makes it sound vary unnatural.... i've been looking up info for days and have found no help, is there and easy answer or is it something that takes a lot more code and even maybe some c++?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, JetPlayer is not suitable here, because it aims to MIDI audio synchronization.
In Jet audio engine, you cannot play a sound right when you hit the button unless you stop all the previously playing sounds (by [JetPlayer#clearQueue()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/JetPlayer.html#clearQueue())).

And there is no easy answer for the android audio delay problem.
Probably you can get better latency with C++ (OpenSL ES), but I don't know much about it.
Please see a related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12309643