# How to use Android audio with low latency

Tags: android, audio, latency

**Problem:**

As you might have heard, Android does not provide with low latency audio API. What I mean by low latency audio is that you should be able to get audio signals from microphone and play the sound without much time gap in-between (e.g., 5-7 ms)

I've tried old java (with AudioRecord and AudioTrack) and "new" OpenSL ES. They are terrible and make app unusable.[The issue was well documented here.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3434) BTW, iOS API can produce about 5-7 ms latency.

**Looking for Workarounds:**

But I am trying to do the low latency audio anyway. [Something like this answer describes.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1448707/931170)

> "However, I was only able to achieve this satisfactorily by writing my
>   own code that did the mixing internally and accessed the low-level
>   audio playback API only for playing the final mixed output. The
>   higher-level ways of playing sounds in the .Net Compact Framework are
>   theoretically capable of polyphony, but in practice they work horribly
>   (lots of glitches, stuttering and distortion)."

Does this make sense for Android? [An answer is discouraging.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5452854/931170)

So my question. Is there really no way to achieve 10 ms audio latency with Android?

To be honest, I am not expecting a solution in some time soon but just wish one great mind have answer to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

android 4.1+ has low latency audio api which should give you below 10ms latency. however the value varies by hardware (welcome to rich diverse world of android).

also feature descriptor of "android.hardware.audio.low_latency" can be used for filter out devices lacking low latency support.

check out http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yc8YrVc47TI&feature=player_de%20tailpage#t=1366s

and this: http://createdigitalmusic.com/2012/07/android-high-performance-audio-in-4-1-and-what-it-means-plus-libpd-goodness-today/

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to get low latency audio on Android devices without modifying the operating system, and even then a lot of the latency can come from the hardware implementation, so the software can't fix that.  This is sad since the Linux kernel is very capable of <5ms audio latency, and much ARM hardware is capable of decent latency.  I had a custom [Linux build running on an old Palm TX](http://vimeo.com/2397102) and that actually had pretty decent latency.

Answer (score 3):

as follow up the feature of `android.hardware.audio.pro` starting in Android 6 promises <20ms round trip times, which we can hope to mean <10ms one-way.